# Result does not show, date validation

Tags: java, class, validation, date, boolean

Any idea why my code won't show the result? Maybe I messed up something, just new to programming by the way.

The goal of the program is to see if the date given by the main class is valid or not, it's not that specific on details such as the month of February and leap years so its pretty simple.

This is my `DataRec.java` :

```
public class DateRec {
    int month, day, year;
    boolean good;

    public DateRec (){

        month = 1;
        day = 1;
        year = 2008;
        good = true;
    }

    public DateRec (int setMonth, int setDay, int setYear){
        month = setMonth;
        day = setDay;
        year = setYear;
    }

    public void validate (){
        if ((month < 0) || (month > 12)){
            good = false;

            if (year == 0) 
                good = false;

            if ((day < 0) || (day > 31))
            good = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (good = true) {
            return String.format("%dd/%dd/%dddd", month, day, year);
        } else {
            return String.format("%dd/%dd/%dddd", month, day, year);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my main class `DataRecTest.java`:

```
public class DateRecTest {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        DateRec today = new DateRec(1,2,2014);
        DateRec anyDay = new DateRec();
        DateRec noDay = new DateRec(13,31,2014);
        anyDay.validate();
        today.validate();
        noDay.validate();
        today.toString();
        anyDay.toString();
        noDay.toString();    
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not printing the results of `toString()` method invocation.

Comment: It should be `if(good == true)` or even simpler, `if (good)`

Comment: Why do you want a day of 0 or a month of 0 to be valid?

Comment: Apart from what Rohit said, `if (good = true) {`  vs `if (good == true) {`

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions and corrections everyone! I got my code working. I'm new to this site. Do I update the code I posted with the working one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Default value of `boolean (good)` is `false` so you need to initialized `good` in `constructor` or `validate()` function i.e

   ```
   good = true; // in constructor or validate function
   ```
2. To see the results you need to print them.

   ```
   //To print in java use System.out.print() or println();
   System.out.println(today.toString());
   //or simply
   System.out.println(today); // println will call today.toString() internally
   ```

**[EDIT]**
Since you are storing result in `good` I recommend the following:

```
 public DateRec (int setMonth, int setDay, int setYear){
    month = setMonth;
    day = setDay;
    year = setYear;
    good = true;
    validate();
 }
```

Now you don't need to call `validate()` every-time;  just check the value of `good`

Answer (score 0):

your validate() is wrong.... It will always be set t false (default value) in whenever you use the 3- argument constructor. You are not setting it to true when date is correct.

change it to,

```
public void validate (){
if ((month <= 0) || (month > 12) || (year==0) || (day<=0) || (day>31)){
    good = false;
}
else
{
 good=true;
}
```